# In Excel 360 i am trying to use =sum(Sumifs(column name, column name to calculate, {"*FH*", "*DN*", " M-F", "M-Th"})) but it gives me #div/0 error

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In Excel 360 i am trying to use =sum(Sumifs(column name, column name to calculate, {"*FH*", "*DN*", " M-F", "M-Th"})) but it gives me #div/0 error
I guess because of blank cells in the columns. Is there a way to have it ignore blanks

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] center. Here is a guide on [ask] and [answer].

Comment: add a second condition to not sum the blank cells, but with the div error I would think something else is goimg on.

Comment: If you perform an operation on a cell that has a DIV/0 error in it, then your operation will also result in a DIV/0.  What you are describing means that one or more of the cells that matched your criteria to be included in the SUMIFS() has a DIV/0 error in it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you check the data to sum. As Max said, if there is one `#DIV/0!` in these data, then you would get the #DIV/0! at last.

Please try to add `"<9E8"` into your sumifs formulas as another condition. It can avoid the effect of #DIV/0!.

For example, here is my simple sample.

[image]